# Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I am working through a javascript problem that asks me to:  Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array.  For example, the input  chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) should return the 'chunked arrays': [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]. Error I am getting is Cannot set property '0' of undefined. Please help.

```
function chunk(arr, size) {

  var k;
  var a=[[]];
  var num=0;

  for(var j=0;j<(arr.length/size);j++){

  for(var i=num,k=0; k<size ;i++,k++)
    {
     a[j][k]=arr[i];
    }

    num+=size;
  }
 return a;
}

chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2, "");
```

Comment: the issue is with this line `a[j][k]=arr[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code using **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var a = [];
  while (arr.length > 0) {
    a.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

In your code you are only initializing one inner array, instead you need to initialize array inside for loop with index

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {

  var k;
  var a = [];
  var num = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < (arr.length / size); j++) {
    a[j] = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < size; num++, k++) {
      a[j][k] = arr[num];
    }
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav. It helped.

Comment: @HarshitJuneja : glad to help :)